# Is there any way to run my android app on android device by localhost

Tags: android, mysql, localhost

I am using MySql database in my android app, can you tell me how can i run it on my android phone ratter than running it on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist data in your app, Android by default has SQLite library pre-installed. Here you can see the tutorial how to use it. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

But as they recommend on their landing page, it is much easier and convenient to use Room library, which works as ORM tool for SQLite on your device.
Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) to room library.